# Parallel co-ordinates plot in R (ggparcoord)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggally

I am facing a somewhat strange situation while plotting a parallel co-ordinates plot using `ggparcoord`. I am running the following code and it is running perfectly fine:

```
# Load required packages
require(GGally)

# Load datasets
data(state)
df <- data.frame(state.x77,
                 State = state.name,
                 Abbrev = state.abb,
                 Region = state.region,
                 Division = state.division
) 

# Generate basic parallel coordinate plot
p <- ggparcoord(data = df,                 
                # Which columns to use in the plot
                columns = 1:4,                 
                # Which column to use for coloring data
                groupColumn = 11,                 
                # Allows order of vertical bars to be modified
                order = "anyClass",                
                # Do not show points
                showPoints = FALSE,                
                # Turn on alpha blending for dense plots
                alphaLines = 0.6,                
                # Turn off box shading range
                shadeBox = NULL,                
                # Will normalize each column's values to [0, 1]
                scale = "uniminmax" # try "std" also
)

# Start with a basic theme
p <- p + theme_minimal()

# Decrease amount of margin around x, y values
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.02, 0.02))
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.02, 0.02))

# Remove axis ticks and labels
p <- p + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(axis.title = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())

# Clear axis lines
p <- p + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())

# Darken vertical lines
p <- p + theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "#bbbbbb"))

# Move label to bottom
p <- p + theme(legend.position = "bottom")

# Figure out y-axis range after GGally scales the data
min_y <- min(p$data$value)
max_y <- max(p$data$value)
pad_y <- (max_y - min_y) * 0.1

# Calculate label positions for each veritcal bar
lab_x <- rep(1:4, times = 2) # 2 times, 1 for min 1 for max
lab_y <- rep(c(min_y - pad_y, max_y + pad_y), each = 4)

# Get min and max values from original dataset
lab_z <- c(sapply(df[, 1:4], min), sapply(df[, 1:4], max))

# Convert to character for use as labels
lab_z <- as.character(lab_z)

# Add labels to plot
p <- p + annotate("text", x = lab_x, y = lab_y, label = lab_z, size = 3)

# Display parallel coordinate plot
print(p)
```

I get the following output:

[image]

The moment I want to subset the data to display fewer `region` levels using the following statement:

```
df<-df[which(df$Region %in% c('South','West','Northeast')),]
```

I start receiving the following error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Why am I getting this error when the number of levels I want to display are clearly more than 2?
Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't repliicate the error....

Comment: I am running exactly the same code mentioned above but only adding this statement: df<-df[which(df$Region %in% c('South','West','Northeast')),]   .   This is used to subset the data to display fewer regions. It is really bizarre if it is not getting replicated. I restarted my RStudio to check again, but I get the same error when using the subset condition after importing the dataset.

Comment: A what point are you running this? What are you running to get the error?

Comment: I'm trying to paste the code but it is too long. I run the 'df' assignment statement, then df<-df[which(df$Region %in% c('South','West','Northeast')),] and finally the assignment statement for 'p' which throws the error.

Comment: Everything runs fine with me, no errors. Could you give specifics on version of `R`, etc?

Comment: Side issue, but your `which` is completely unnecessary inside `[`.

Comment: `which` is subsetting the dataframe in this case depending on `region`

Comment: @Patthebug no, `[` is subsetting the data.frame, `which` is changing your subset from being based on a boolean to being based on a column index. `x <- 1:10; x[x < 5]; x[which(x < 5)]`. The `which` is unnecessary. (Though it can help if you have `NA`s you don't want.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured what the problem was. I had to convert the column into factor.

```
df$Region <- factor(df$Region)
```

The above piece of code fixes the error.